# Boundedness in $L^p$ spaces

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

The question is:
For $n\geq 1,f_n:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ measurable. Provide a counter example to the following: If the sequence $\{f_n\}_n$ is bounded in $L^4(\mathbb{R}^d)$ then it is bounded in  $L^3(\mathbb{R}^d)$.

Since $L^4\subseteq L^3 $ this seems quite correct to me and I cannot think of a counter example.

Otherwise with the same hypothesis, I want to prove that if the sequence $\{f_n\}_n$ is a convergent sequence in $L^3(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and bounded in  $L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^d)$ then $\{f_n\}_n$ is a convergent sequence in $L^4(\mathbb{R}^d)$.
It seems quite intuitive but I have hard time coming up with a rigorous proof.

Comment: "Since $L^4\subseteq L^3$" : are you sure ?

Comment: It is true when the domain is bounded indeed, here it is not. Still cannot find a counter example though.

Answer (score 2):

$L^4\subseteq L^3$ is not necessarily true when the measure space is infinite, and it is famously false for $\Bbb R^n$ measure spaces. $L^p\subseteq L^q$ is just not true for $p\le q$ in that context.

A good, intuitive example is the function $x^{-p}$. It has a convergent integral over $\Bbb R_{\ge1}$ if and only if $p\gt 1$, similar to the series $\sum n^{-p}$

Let $d=1$ and let $f_n$ be any sequence of measurable functions $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ converging to $x^{-2/7}$. Such a sequence exists by the simple approximation theorem, or even just by setting $f_n:=x^{-2/7}\chi_{[1,\infty)}$ for all $n$. Can you see how $f_n$ is bounded in $L^4$ but not in $L^3$?

Comment: I have one question though. In your example, I have to show that $\int_\mathbb{R}|x^{-2/7}|^4<\infty$ but don't we have a problem around zero? Otherwise I see the idea.

Comment: @Omen I’m sorry, my first example had an error. We need to integrate from $1\to\infty$ for the example to work

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Note that my original mistaken example demonstrates that $L^3\subseteq L^4$ is also false: let $f_n:=x^{-2/7}\cdot\chi_{(0,1]}$. $f_n$ are $L^3$-integrable but not $L^4$-integrable. @Omer You’re welcome, anyway